# jquerymobile wp7 changePage

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

Been working on a jquerymobile project and hit a problem in WP7 (and IE7).

At first I had all the content in one big page, but then WP7 didn't load any pages, so I had to seperate the pages into different .htm files.

So here is what I have. One page I have a  which needs to take values from some s, run a function and then go to the next page and display a result.

All this is on page 'three' by the way

initially I had

```
 <a id="calculate_square" href="results.html">Calculate volume</a>
```

But I couldn't get it to fun a function because it straight away directs to results.html

so instead I have

```
 <a id="calculate_square" href="#">Calculate volume</a>
```

and the following js code:

```
$('#three').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
    $('#calculate_square').click(function() {
        var height = $('#height').val();
        var width = $('#width').val();
        var depth = $('#depth').val();

        if(height == 0 || width == 0 || depth == 0){
            alert("something is blank");
        }
        else {
            calculateSquare();
            $.mobile.changePage("results.html");
        }   
    });
});
```

Which works fine everywhere except WP7/IE7, which, if the inputs are empty, returns the alert, but doesn't seem to handle the $.mobile.changePage("results.html");

I'm using the latest version 1.0a4.1.

So am I going about this the wrong way? Any help would be great. Can't believe this has to work on WP7 :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would change the link to a button as jQM might be still trying to use it as navigation.

This:

```
<a id="calculate_square" href="#">Calculate volume</a>
```

to:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate volume" id="calculate_square" />
```

As for your changePage(), there are more options in you need to submit data, transition, track, etc... Here are the docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/api/methods.html

for Example I've used the changePage() like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage({
    url: 'request.php?page=foo', 
    type: 'post', 
    data: $('form#myForm').serialize()
},'slide',false,false);
```

This handles the POST submission as well and the navigation.

As you wp7 does it have a debug console to display errors?

Comment: Thanks Phill
Changing the markup to use  an <input> actually stops the page loading in IE7! This is so frustrating. So my button is on page2. When choosing the link on page1, I just get the loading spinner.

I must be doing something wrong.

If I stick with the <a>, in WP7 I get the error when trying to use the ChangePage method - "Exception thrown and not caught"

Comment: I've posted on the jquerymobile forum but no responses there 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/changepage-wp7-bug